# Why 32bit apppool would be more efficient than 64bit?

Tags: asp.net, xslt, iis, webforms

We have these 2 configurations

- Windows Server 2003, IIS6, 32bit app pool, 4gb RAM, 4 cpu, .net 4 installed
- Windows Server 2012, IIS8, 64bit app pool, 16gb RAM, 4 cpu, .net 4.5 installed

The technologies are the followings :

- Asp.net 4.0 webforms
- The rendering is mainly xml/xslt transformation (XslCompiledTransform)
- AppFabric as outputcache (standalone, not in azure)
- Xml files and XslCompiledTransform are cached in memory with the Cache API

After a couple of days we saw that the 2012 servers were much slower than the 2003 (sometime 10 times slower !!). After a couple of days of head scratching and testing (perfmon, dottrace) we tried to set the 2012 app pool to 32bit and it worked ! Now the 2012 servers are running faster.

First question : can you explain this ? My only guess is the client library for AppFabric were made for 32bit system ...

Second question : how would you do with all the tools in the world (perfmon, windbg, dottrace whatever) to find that the 64bit was the problem here ?

Comment: This is more about server configuration than programming...

Comment: it's about performance,  library and debugging as well